# Rails rewrite how to rewrite this code to ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a this class middleware:

```
class RedirectIt
require "net/https"
require "uri"
require 'open-uri'

  APP_DOMAIN = 'http://www.mydomain.com'
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
        request = Rack::Request.new(env)
        response = Rack::Response.new(env)
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=#{84.hours.to_i}"
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
        response.body = "#{open('http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/asdas.png').read}"
  end

end
```

The problem is just that it gives the error:

```
Started GET "/?view=boks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-01 04:07:58 +0200

NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=):
```

Are am doing something wrong? I have tried to rewrite this code I had in the controller:

```
def image_proxy
  image_url = "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket#{request.path}"
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=#{84.hours.to_i}"
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
  render :text => open(image_url, "rb").read
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution.

```
    #PROXY BILLEDER
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
    headers['Cache-Control'] = "public, max-age=#{84.hours.to_i}"
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
    headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline'
    response_body = "#{(open('http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket#{request.path()}')).read}"
    [status, headers, response_body]
```